# Angular video: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/Videoes/pakistan.mp4

Tags: angular, angular7

video or image from local path is not showing, 
how to play video from local src path in angular.

code:

```
<video src="file:///E:/Videoes/pakistan.mp4" autoplay controls width="750" height="450px">
</video>
```

Error image is attached as below:

[image: Error image is here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Vne.jpg)

Comment: Let's assume that this works. Will you tell all the visitors of your webapp to make sure they run Windows and not another OS, then to create a drive E: and a directory Videoes, then to somehow download a video from somewhere, name it pakistan.mp4 and to store it in this directory, then to finally click Play to run the video? Would that make sense? Wouldn't it be much simpler to host the video on your web site and to let the users play the video directly, by downloading it over http(s)?

Comment: Rembember that this is client code, running on the client (user) machine. The user will request the resource containing these lines of code from your server, but it will be executed locally by their browser. When their browser read src="file:// ..." it will look in the users local file system for this file. It won't be there.